# How to understand $\partial_t \rho_t+\operatorname{div}\left(v_t \rho_t\right)=0$ in the distributional sense?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I'm reading section *Continuity equation and Benamou–Brenier* in these [notes](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Eafigalli/lecture-notes-pdf/An-introduction-to-optimal-transport-and-Wasserstein-gradient-flows.pdf), i.e.,

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a convex set $\left(\Omega=\mathbb{R}^d\right.$ is admissible), let $\bar{\rho}_0 \in \mathcal{P}_2(\Omega)$ be a probability density with finite second moment, and let $v:[0, T] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a smooth bounded vector field tangent to the boundary of $\Omega$. Let $X(t, x)$ denote the flow of $v$, namely
> $$
> (5.1) \quad
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \dot{X}(t, x)=v(t, X(t, x)), \\
> X(0, x)=x
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> and set $\rho_t=(X(t))_{\#} \bar{\rho}_0$. Note that, since $v$ is tangent to the boundary, the flow remains inside $\Omega$, hence $\rho_t \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
>
> **Lemma 5.1.** Let $v_t(\cdot):=v(t, \cdot)$. Then $\left(\rho_t, v_t\right)$ solves continuity equation
> $$
> (5.2) \quad
> \partial_t \rho_t+\operatorname{div}\left(v_t \rho_t\right)=0
> $$
> in the distributional sense.
>
> **Proof.** Let $\psi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, and consider the function $t \mapsto \int_{\Omega} \rho_t(x) \psi(x) d x$. Then, using the definitions of $X$ and $\rho_t$, we get
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \int_{\Omega} \partial_t \rho_t(x) \psi(x) d x & =\frac{d}{d t} \int_{\Omega} \rho_t(x) \psi(x) d x \stackrel{(i)}{=} \frac{d}{d t} \int_{\Omega} \psi(X(t, x)) \bar{\rho}_0(x) d x \\
> & =\int_{\Omega} \nabla \psi(X(t, x)) \cdot \dot{X}(t, x) \bar{\rho}_0(x) d x \\
> & \stackrel{(i i)}{=} \int_{\Omega} \nabla \psi(X(t, x)) \cdot v_t(X(t, x)) \bar{\rho}_0(x) d x \\
> & \stackrel{(i i i)}{=} \int_{\Omega} \nabla \psi(x) \cdot v_t(x) \rho_t(x) d x=-\int_{\Omega} \psi(x) \operatorname{div}\left(v_t \rho_t\right) d x
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where (i) and (iii) follow from $\rho_t=(X(t))_{\#} \bar{\rho}_0$, while (ii) follows from (5.1).

I'm not familiar with distribution theory. Could you confirm if I understand the statement of **Lemma 5.1.** correctly? Thank you so much for your help!

---

**My understanding** By assumption, $v$ is a bounded smooth vector field. On the other hand, no smoothness condition is imposed on $\bar{\rho}_0$. However, $\rho_t$ is differentiable. Then $\partial_t \rho_t$  and $\operatorname{div}\left(v_t \rho_t\right)$ makes sense as measurable functions. So $\partial_t \rho_t+\operatorname{div}\left(v_t \rho_t\right)=0$ in the distributional sense if and only if $\partial_t \rho_t (x)+\operatorname{div}\left(v_t \rho_t\right) (x)=0$ for a.e. $(t, x) \in [0, T] \times \Omega$.

Comment: A (sufficiently nice) function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ defines a linear functional on $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ by $\varphi\mapsto\int_\Omega \varphi(x)f(x)~\mathrm{d}x$. This functional is the distribution associated with $f$. The result then states that the distribution associated with $\partial_t\rho_t+\operatorname{div}(v_t\rho_t)$ is identically zero

Comment: @Lorago I got your idea, but can you have a check on my above understanding?

Comment: Is $\rho_t=(X(t))_{\#} \bar{\rho}_0$ really defined pointwise in $\Omega$? Isn't it a function in $t$ but a probability density (a measure) in space?

Comment: @md2perpe I'm also not clear about that point...

Comment: If we take $\Omega=\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2\leq 1 \},$ can we then have $\bar{\rho}_0$ be a unit point mass at $(\frac12,0)$ and $v=(-y,x)$? If so, then I think that $\rho_t$ should be a unit point mass somewhere on the circle $x^2+y^2=\frac14,$ moving along that circle as $t$ increases.

Comment: @md2perpe Yess, I think the author is a little bit non-rigorous at that point. I have a strongly related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456284/continuity-equation-partial-t-mu-t-operatornamediv-v-t-mu-t-0-are-the)...

Comment: Even if a probability density must be a function then I suppose that we can have $\bar{\rho}_0$ be the indicator function of some set. Also $\rho_t$ will be the indicator function of some set. At the borders of this set the gradient is not defined in the classical sense, but it is defined in a distributional sense. Therefore we cannot take values at $(t,x)$ but must integrate against a test function.

Comment: @md2perpe Could you explain what $\partial_t \rho_t$ means in the sense of distribution when $\rho_t$ is a bona fide probability measure (without density)?

Comment: $\partial_t\rho_t$ is the linear functional $C^\infty_c([0,T]\times\Omega) \to \mathbb C$ given by $$\phi \mapsto -\iint \rho_t(t,x) \, \partial_t\phi(t,x) \, dt\,dx.$$